# What do these $ variables mean for parsing nginx?

Tags: nginx, awk

I need to parse and regex my nginx logs for a set of urls. For example, from some links that I found online, this awk command will find the 25 most popular urls:

```
cat access.log | awk '{ print $7 }' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -n 25
```

This line will find most requested urls with a certain pattern:

```
awk -F\" '($2 ~ "ref"){print $2}' access.log | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -r
```

What I need to do is to combine both of these to find the top `x` urls with a regex pattern. For example, if I want to find the most popular urls with "cupcake" in the url, how would I go about doing this. Furthermore, I'm having a tough time understanding what the `$` variables mean. What do the `$2` or `$7` variables refer to? If I can discern that then I think I'll be on my way. A push in the right direction would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: `awk '{ print $7 }'` means awk will print 7th column of the file. This is very basic of awk, please have some reading about, `$1`,`$2`.... and `$0`. Some builtin variables like `FS` `OFS` `NF` `NR`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

awk splits the input line into columns, each column value can be referred by $x.